# MPMoviePlayerController stopped working in 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, video, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play a live streaming m3u8 video for older devices (3.1.2).  This worked fine until this morning.  I tried changing the scalingMode to resolve another issue, and now the player does not work at all.  I went back to older backups that worked, and they don't work, either.

While debugging, control goes into [mMPPlayer play] and never returns.  This also locks up my app.

Has something changed with MPMoviePlayerController, or did I break something in XCode?

My app was scheduled to start moving to production today, so I'm really in a bind, here.  :(

Here's the warning that I get:

Warning: MPMoviePlayerController may not support file of type m3u8

And here's my code:

MyViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface WatchNowViewController : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerController *mMPPlayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)           MPMoviePlayerController *mMPPlayer;

@end
```

MyViewController.m:

```
        mMPPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myVideo.m3u8"]];
        mMPPlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
        mMPPlayer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [mMPPlayer play];
NSLog("Control never returns to here");
```

Comment: have you upgraded the xcode or iPhone sdk? or is there any changes in stream files?

Comment: That warning is normal and can be ignored. Try another stream - e.g. Apple's blip-blop example. Maybe the change happened on your server and not on your client.

Comment: Thanks, Till.  Do you have a link to the blip-blop example?  I'm having trouble finding it.'

Comment: Here they are http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to us as well. Not sure what went wrong. The encrypted streams just stopped playing in 3.2. Try the m3u8 url in the iPad safari and check if it plays there. If it doesn't play in iPad safari as well, try an unencrypted stream. As per my experience, an unencrypted stream played in 3.2 without issues.

Comment: When did this hit you guys?  Today?  The stream plays in iPad and iPhone 4.0, but I'm using the view controller (MPMoviePlayerViewController) for those.  I just forced it to use MPMoviePlayerController, and I get sound, but no video.  I think I saw a thread somewhere else that talked about having to manually add the view for the player.  I didn't have to do that before, so I overlooked that thread.  I'll try to find it again.

Comment: Happened some days back. Since we were in a rush to get the app out, we left it and made the deployment target of the app to be iOS 4.2 and above.

Comment: I have a feeling I may have to do the same.  I found something useful, here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099662/mpmovieplayercontroller-not-working-in-iphone-sdk-4-help-needed .  I added [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200); and was able to get this to work on iPad.  (mMPPlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit; will give you a nicely-fitted landscape / portrait view)  HOWEVER, this will NOT work on iPhone 3.1.2. I get a SIGABRT error when I try to make the frame or add the view.  It's like this was completely pulled.

Comment: @user359519 The view-property did not exist prior to iOS 3.2, hence you need to check for its existence before using it (for projects targeting anything below 3.2) - see respondsToSelector:.

Comment: It's working, now.  The only thing I changed was my code signing identity.  I changed it back, and it still works, so I don't think that was the issue.  Another app that uses the same feed is working now, as well.  (It was broken in synch with mine.)  I'm totally baffled, but glad it's working.  I still learned a lot from your comments.  Thanks, everyone!